# ArgumentException: The 'ClientId' option must be provided

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, amazon-aws, entity-framework-core

Estou subindo minha aplicação para os servidores aws. Quando eu rodo a aplicação localmente ela funciona perfeitamente, mas quando eu testo ela na nuvem recebo o seguinte erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O parametro 'ClienteId' é a minha chave para poder fazer login com o Google, e essa chave fica no arquivo secrets.json.

Não sei como continuar, pois como disse localmente a aplicação funciona

Comment: Você considerou passar para o `appsetings.json` e puxar de lá no startup?

Comment: Sim, consegui fazer isso.

Comment: Então você não conseguiu é implementar o secret manager do aws?